# ajuda em como remover uma determinada string

Tags: java

**conteúdo do teste.txt**

```
<td><input type="radio" name="pg1" value="SIM" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="pg1" value="NÃO" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="pg2" value="SIM" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="pg2" value="NÃO" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="pg3" value="SIM" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="pg3" value="NÃO" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="pg4" value="SIM" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="pg4" value="NÃO" /></td>
```

neste programa ele salva todo o conjunto de strings contendo a ocorrência `name=` dentro um arraylist de objetos. Após seu armazenamento, vou fazer o tratamento de cada string.

```
    Reader lerArquivo = new FileReader("teste.txt");
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(lerArquivo);
    ArrayList<Perguntas> valores = new ArrayList<>();

    String linha;
    String delims = "\"";

    while ((linha = br2.readLine()) != null) {

        if (linha.contains("name=")) {

            Perguntas form = new Perguntas();
            form.setNomeDaPergunta(linha);
            valores.add(form);

        }

    }
    System.out.println("valores.size()-> " + valores.size());
    //fazendo o tratamento das strings
    for (int i = 0; i < valores.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println("-> " + valores.get(i).getNomeDaPergunta());
    }

    lerArquivo.close();
    br2.close();
```

dentro da arraylist de objetos foi armazenado isto (mandei printar o que tinha dentro da arraylist de objetos)

```
<td><input type="radio" name="pg1" value="SIM" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="pg1" value="NÃO" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="pg2" value="SIM" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="pg2" value="NÃO" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="pg3" value="SIM" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="pg3" value="NÃO" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="pg4" value="SIM" /></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="pg4" value="NÃO" /></td>
```

a minha pergunta:
Como eu procuro a string name, depois como eu faço pra remover todo o seu conteúdo anterior e posterior da segunda aspas, por exemplo:

```
String pegaValorName = "<td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"pg4\" value=\"NÃO\" /></td>";
```

a `pegaValorName` passar a ser apenas: pg4

Comment: E o php onde fica no seu problema?

Comment: pois é.. removi o php da tags

Comment: Tenho um formulário gigantesco em php (tenho 40 formulários para desenvolver, o número de perguntas vai até o número 100 e a nomenclatura varia muito), estou fazendo um código pra facilitar a minha vida na hora de criar o banco de dados (com create table). a ideia é ler esse o index.php (por enquanto estou fazendo em .txt), pegar todos os name="algo" e gerar o create table de forma automática. Se existir uma outra forma de implementar isso, seja em java, php ou outra linguagem, estaria aberto para ajuda. Mas aceitei a modificação.

Comment: Já viu uma biblioteca chamada **`Jsoup`**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sou especialista em Java, mas isso deve resolver:

```
String pegaValorName = "<td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"pg4\" value=\"NAO\" /></td>"; 
String partes[] = pegaValorName.split("name=\"");
partes = partes[1].split("\"");
String valorName = partes[0];
System.out.println(valorName);
```

Pode ver funcionando [aqui](http://ideone.com/e3Zjg0).